# Of all the shows "TNG" and later, why didn't "DS9" have any slow motion exterior video shots?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-deep-space-nine

On *TNG* and *Voyager*, many of the exterior shots of the ships were done in slow motion video frame rates (for those who don't understand what I mean, the same rate as *Curb Your Enthusiasm* was until like 2011), yet *DS9* was purely on film (although edited on video).

I know they all were shot on film, but (except for *TNG* which did a lot of the editing on film) purely edited on video, yet *DS9* looks like film throughout its entire run in every scene.
*Voyager* had slow motion exterior shots just like *TNG* but I think more.

Strangely enough *Seinfeld* (prior to remastering) did this as well. I believe *Seinfeld* was shot on film but edited on video too.

Exterior also includes battle scenes as well.

Comment: related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104831/was-seinfeld-shot-on-film-but-edited-on-video-much-like-tng-ds9-and-vo