# Was "Seinfeld" shot on film, but edited on video much like "TNG," "DS9," and "Voyager"?

Tags: seinfeld

On the SD versions of the show, which used to air a long time ago (as everything is on HD), some exterior shots of the apartments were in the same framerate as *Curb Your Enthusiasm* (from when it started until they switched to film).

Comment: See [this discussion](https://www.ign.com/boards/threads/how-are-episodes-of-seinfeld-shown-now-in-hd.250060377/), and skip straight down to see the answer provided by entilza on 15th February 2014.